# how can I create an alias with arguments in multiple lines (like SH files)

Tags: unix, redhat, tcsh, aliases

i am on RedHat 6.
i am trying to create an alias that takes arguments, but in order to make the alias more "readable" i want to create it in multiple lines (see code below)
The alias is in a text file called "reg_aliases"

Example:
**instead of**

```
   alias run_reg ' svn up ; cd project ; compile \!* ; cd project2 ; compile \!* '
```

**desired**:

```
   alias run_reg ' svn up 
   cd project ; compile \\!* ;
   cd project2 ; compile \\!* ; '
```

i tried to add "\" after each line but the last one, it did not work either.

Original Code:

```
alias comp_env_none 'arun -c -toppath \\!* -sncomp'
alias run_reg ' svn up $PROJECT; cd $PROJECT/work; comp_env_none $TOP -clean; cd $PROJECT/work_2 ; comp_env_none $TOP2 ; vmanager -gui \\!* '
```

**tried to do this**:

```
    alias run_reg ' svn up $PROJECT; \
    cd $PROJECT/work; comp_env_none $TOP -clean; \
    cd $PROJECT/work_2 ; comp_env_none $TOP2 ; \
    vmanager -gui \!* '
```

and it did not work.
any suggestion on how to create such an alias ?

Comment: what do you mean by that ?
can it be done in a text ?

Comment: it does not work.
if i add this to my aliases file, and try to source it, it fails on "badly placed ()"

i also removed the ";" from lines.

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: running "ps -p $$" gives me "tcsh"
OS is RH6
aliases file in "ASCII text"

Comment: What you **tried to do** seems correct; _it did not work_ in which way?

Comment: @MichaelMarjieh Oh, I erroneously assumed a POSIX shell. Never mind my previous comments.